# Scala instance variable initialization using Spring annotation

Tags: spring, scala

I find myself doing a lot of the following, where Spring fills in the value for HttpClient, **correctly**, upon package scanning.

```
@Resource(name = "httpClient")
val httpClient: CloseableHttpClient = null// <-- NAGS ME
```

That said, the code looks like it's cheating. On one hand a `null` is assigned, however at runtime, the correct value magically appears.

I can make it a `var`but it really does not change during the lifetime of the instance once it's initialized.

I am new to Scala, so first off, am I doing something totally off? If so what would you suggest as ways to do the elegantly and without being too wordy?

Here are the alternatives I can think of

1. Use constructor injection where possible. My issue here is that the constructor gets lost in all the annotation.
2. Use an `@Configuration` bean and configure. This lacks the nice correlation that the `@Resource` annotation brings.

Any suggestions?

Thanks all in anticipation.